# Why can't decltype work with overloaded functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, decltype

`decltype` fails if the function you're calling it on is overloaded, as in this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int test(double x, double y);
double test(int x, int y);
char test(char x, int y);

int main()
{
  std::cout << decltype(test) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
error: decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function
```

I understand that this is because `decltype` can't figure out which function you're trying to get the type of. But why isn't there another way to make this work, like this:

```
std::cout << decltype(test(double, double)) << std::endl;
```

or this:

```
double x = 5, y = 2;
std::cout << decltype(test(x, y)) << std::endl;
```

Since a function cannot be overloaded simply based on return type, wouldn't passing either datatypes or actual variables to the `decltype` call be enough to tell it which of the overloads it's supposed to examine? What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by outputting a type, but your last code piece works apart from that.

Comment: @chris It's a bit of test code. A real code bit using `decltype` failed when I gave it overloaded functions, and I was trying to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Are you trying to find the return type or the type of the actual function?

Comment: @chris I'm pretty sure the code is getting the function's type. The code itself is actually in a template library that's above my skill level, but it appears to be getting the type of a template function.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I seem to remember that `decltype` is usually used together with `declval`, in a way that `declval` parameters are passed into a function to get back the type.

Comment: @rwong `declval` is not in use in this code segment. After studying the library more, I think it's trying to use the function's return type to create a matching function of the same type.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To figure out the type of the function from the type of the arguments you'd pass, you can "build" the return type by using `decltype` and "calling" it with those types, and then add on the parameter list to piece the entire type together.

```
template<typename... Ts>
using TestType = decltype(test(std::declval<Ts>()...))(Ts...);
```

Doing `TestType<double, double>` will result in the type `int(double, double)`. You can find a full example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc5bc715a7be11cc).

Alternatively, you might find the trailing return type syntax more readable:

```
template<typename... Ts>
using TestType = auto(Ts...) -> decltype(test(std::declval<Ts>()...));
```

Comment: Is there any alternative to this that would build on VS 2013? The example code yields errors like `error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Ts'`, `error C3203: 'TestType' : unspecialized alias template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Ty1', expected a real type`.

Comment: I don't have 2013 handy at the moment (it works with the web compiler, which I think is 2015). Something you can try is to use a templated structure with a `type` typedef. `template<typename... Ts> struct TestType {typedef ... type;};`, with usage `TestType<int, int>::type`

Comment: Would this still work if the overloaded function was a member function of a class?

Comment: @VishalSubramanyam, Yes, you'd call the function using the appropriate syntax (`declval` can give you a "fake object" to call it on just like it provides "fake objects" for the arguments), and `decltype` would be the type of the result. However, it's worth noting that C++17 added [`invoke_result`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of), which improves upon `result_of` to the point that the `decltype` approach feels like reinventing that.

Comment: ```std::invoke_result``` seems to work only for callable objects and not for simple functions? Is this right?

Comment: Also, I tried using a non-static member function with the code you've given in the answer, and I get an error that says ```Call to non-static member function without an object argument``` despite me using ```declval```

Comment: @VishalSubramanyam, It can still take a function reference or function pointer type. However, I had forgotten at the time that we're dealing with an overloaded function where getting its type isn't feasible. For the second part, you need to use the appropriate calling syntax: `object.foo(args)`. `declval<object type>()` can take the place of `object` when you don't have one handy and the code is too generic to just construct one. Remember to take value category (lvalue vs. rvalue etc.) into account as well when using `declval` if it could affect which overload is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you may be looking for `std::result_of<>`

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) page.

Comment: To use `result_of`, you need the type. And the problem is - you don't have the type because there isn't one type.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way: use `std::declval` to generate a fake object, then use `decltype`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
int myfunc(int a)
{
    return a;
}
float myfunc(float a)
{
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    decltype(myfunc(std::declval<float>())) a;  // return type
    std::function<decltype(a)(float)> fun;      // function type
    return 0;
}
```