# Confusion about what is actually happening with this decltype statement

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

So I was taking a look through http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of and saw the syntax for doing `result_of` of a member function and I just don't understand what is going on with that decltype.

Why do the args come after the decltype? Wouldn't they be important in figuring out the type of the member function? In my mind I imagine that instead of `decltype(&C::Func)(C, char, int&)` it should be `decltype(&C::Func(C, char, int&))` or something of the like, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it. Can anyone please explain why it is this syntax?

Answer (score 3):

`std::result_of` takes a template argument of the form `F(A...)`. `F` should be a type that is callable, such as a function type or a class type with an overloaded `operator()`. `A...` should be a sequence of argument types.

Therefore, if you have some expression `e` and some argument types `A...` and you want to know what result type you will get if you call `e` with arguments of types `A...` then you would put `F` = `decltype(e)` in `std::result_of<F(A...)>`, that is, `std::result_of<decltype(e)(A...)>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm copying the relevant code from the example that you pointed to:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct C {
    double Func(char, int&);
};

int main()
{
    // result_of can be used with a pointer to member function as follows
    std::result_of<decltype(&C::Func)(C, char, int&)>::type g = 3.14;
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(g), double>::value, "");
}
```

1. `decltype(&C::Func)` is the declared type of method `Func` of `C`, which is a function taking a `C` reference (corresponding to `this`), a `char` and an `int` reference.
2. Let us call this type `T`.
3. Then, `result_of<T(...)>::type` will be the type of the result of applying a function of type `T` to the arguments whose types you specify in the parentheses.
4. Therefore, in this example, `result_of<decltype(&C::Func)(C, char, int&)>::type` will be `double`.

Comment: See now maybe this is where I'm going wrong here, you say in 1. that decltype(&C::Func) is a function taking reference, char, and int, so then what happens when Func is overloaded? then what is decltype(&C::Func) actually the type of?

Comment: @legionYou then get [a compiler error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291737).

Comment: So then what is the point of having to specify the arguments after the decltype, you would already know from that pointer what the return type is

Comment: There's also function/method overloading.

Comment: Right but if you can't do decltype(&C::Func) on an overloaded member function then how the hell would function/method overloading working just by tagging those on?

Comment: @legion The primary goal is to handle function objects (i.e., classes that overload `operator()`).

Answer (score 0):

As you are aware, the type `T1(T2,T3)` means a function returning a value of `T1` and taking arguments of type `T2` and `T3`. As soon as you are working with values of that type, you are bound to that interpretation.

`std::result_of` does *not* deal with any values, just with a type of the form `T1(T2,T3)`, so it technically has the freedom to interpret the types any way it likes. And it actually does! If `std::result_of` would be parametrized over the type of a function, and return the return type of that function, the result (i.e. nested `type` member) would just be `T1`, but it isn't. The standard writers chose to implement a different functionality: `std::result_of` takes the type `T1` in it's type parameter not to be the return type of the function to be determined, but the *complete* type of some [callable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable) thing (e.g. a function pointer), and it will return the type returned by that callable thing when passed the arguments `T1` and `T2`.

Example time!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

int main(void)
{
  // define the type of a function
  typedef int ftype(char, long);

  // (A) doesn't compile: you can't call an int 
  std::cout << typeid(std::result_of<int(char,long)>).name() << '\n';
  // (B) doesn't compile: A the return type of a function may not be a function
  std::cout << typeid(std::result_of<ftype(char,long)>::type).name() << '\n';
  // (C) does compile and print the typeid name of int. On g++ this is "i"
  std::cout << typeid(std::result_of<ftype*(char,long)>::type).name() << '\n';
}
```

Case (A) fails, as `int` is not callable, although the template parameter itself is well-formed. Case (B) fails, as the template parameter is *not* well-formed. In `T1(T2,T3)`, `T1` must not be a function type, as types describing a function returning a function are forbidden. Case (C) has a valid template parameter, in which the return type of the "function" describes a callable type, so `std::result_of` is applicable.

With this context in mind, the answer to your question is likely obvious. The expression `decltype(&C::Func)(C, char, int&)` describes a function type returning `decltype(&C::Func)` and taking the parameter types `C`, `char` and `int &`. As already discussed, the return type has to be something [callable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable), which is the case for `decltype(&C::Func)`, as it is the pointer-to-member-function type `double (C::*)(char, int&)`. According to the definition of the INVOKE operation (see the page about callable), this type is callable with a parameter list `(C, char, int&)`, so the application `std::result_of` to `decltype(&C::Func)(C, char, int&)` is valid.

The alternative you suggest: `std::result_of<decltype(&C::Func(C, char, int&))>` is not valid, as `&C::Func(C, char, int&)` is not a valid expression. If you want to constrain the type (in case there are multiple overloads of `Func`), you can do that using a cast, though. `decltype(static_cast<double (C::*)(int, char&)>(&C::Func))` is a valid expression, returning (no surprise there) the type `double (C::*)(int, char&)`. But like in example (A), this is not a type you may apply `std::result_of` on.

The really interesting use-case for std::result_of is the case in which `T1`, the callable type, is a function object. By passing the type of a function object to `std::result_of` as `T1`, you are passing *all function-call operators* of that object at the same time and you can have `std::result_of` pick the right one using overload resolution. Passing "all the `Func` functions" like you pass "all the `operator()` functions" is not possible, because `std::result_of` is hardwired to look for `operator()` in case of objects, and you can't use the address-of operator to map `operator()` invocations to `Func()` invocations. You can write a template doing this mapping, though:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

class S {
public:
  int Func(int);
  double Func(float, float);
};

template <typename T>
class call_Func : public T {
public:
  template<typename... args>
  auto operator()(args... vals) -> decltype(this->Func(vals...)) { return this->Func(vals...); }
};

int main(void)
{
  std::cout << typeid(std::result_of<call_Func<S>(int)>::type).name() << '\n';
}
```

The template call_Func redirects calling `operator()` on `call_Func<S>` to calling Func on the base class `S` (one should use `std::forward`, though), but note you can not write a "generic redirector" that gets the name of the function to redirect the function call operator to as template parameter, as you can neither pass overload set nor names as template parameters, but just types and constant values (for non-type parameters). Pointer-to-member-functions are one kind of constant value, but you already lost the overloading as soon as you form such a pointer.