# no type named "type" in "std::result_of" ; get return type from overloading functions

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates, overloading, decltype, result-of

I am learning how to get `type` of the return value of overloaded function `test()` vs `test(double)`.

I modified code from [a SO answer (by chris)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22292012/3577745).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

int test();
double test(double x);

template<typename... Ts>
using TestType = decltype(test(std::declval<Ts>()...))(Ts...);

int main() {
    std::result_of< TestType<double> >::type n = 0;
     //^ ### compile error ###
    using doubleDat = std::result_of< TestType<double> >::type ;
    doubleDat n=0;
}
```

I got a compile error.

> error: no type named 'type' in 'std::result_of'

**As I understand:-**

- `TestType<...>` is "variadic template".
  In my own words, it acts like *a packed abbreviation* that have any amount of parameters.
- The `TestType<double>` is *id* of the `test(double)` function.
- `std::result_of<TestType<double>>::type` is the return type of `test(double)`.
  `doubleDat` should be `double`.

**Question:** Why it doesn't compile?    How to solve it?

I have read these :-

- [decltype for overloaded member function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40135561/3577745) - no example about `std::result_of`
- [c++: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(std::unordered_map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950835) - issue related to thread rather than `std::result_of`

**Clue:** After a long search, I get faint smell that my code suffers "Most vexing parse".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at what your `TestType<double>` expands to:

```
test(std::declval<double>())(double)
```

`test(std::decvlal<double>)` is `double` so you get `double(double)`

`result_of<double(double)>::type` asks if you can invoke a `double` with an argument of type `double`.

The answer is no, because `double` is not callable, so there's no nested type.

You need to read the documentation for `result_of` to understand how to use it. The type `result_of<F(Arg)>::type` is the result of invoking an `F` with an argument `Arg`. If `F` is callable with an argument `Arg` you get the return type, if it is not callable with an argument `Arg` then the nested `type` doesn't exist.

So this would work:

```
using func_type = TestType<double>;
using doubleDat = std::result_of<func_type*(double)>::type;
```

This creates an alias for a function of type `TestType<double>` (i.e. `double(double)`) and then asks if you can invoke a pointer to that type (i.e. `double(*)(double)`) with an argument of type `double`. And you can, so you the `type` is valid.

Comment: Was just about to write my own answer after experimenting. You beat me to it.

Comment: I want to be good at these things.  (I am learning based on trial and error slowly. )  How to get abundant knowledge around this area in one big chunk?  Is there any book , e.g. which one in [an C++ book SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) ,  covering these topics in depth?  tutorial video?  Do you write some C++ books?

Comment: Thank.  I guess I have to wear an armor now.