# Using std::result_of with an overloaded method

Tags: c++, overloading, result-of

I added an overloaded method to an existing class, which now causes a compilation error in our unit tests.

I have replicated the issue with the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

class Foo
{
    public:
    Foo() {};
    int bar(const std::string & s) {return 1;};
    int bar(const std::string & s, long l) {return 2;};
    int bar2(const std::string & s) {return 3;};
};

int main()
{
    // compiles
    std::is_same<std::result_of<decltype(&Foo::bar2)(Foo, const std::string &)>::type, int>::value;

    // does not compile
    std::is_same<std::result_of<decltype(&Foo::bar)(Foo, const std::string &)>::type, int>::value;
    return 0;
}
```

What changes do I need to make to the line that does not compile so that I can test the return of an overloaded method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22291737/1460794

Comment: `std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<Foo&>().bar("")), int>::value`

Comment: @Muscampester thanks, the accepted answer helped me understand Piotr's comment above

Comment: Also useful: https://arne-mertz.de/2017/01/decltype-declval/

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I think posting the comment as an answer is justified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An overloaded function name represents all overloads, each having its own address. Thus it cannot be resolved to a certain overload unless there exists a supporting context, e.g., a static cast is used:

```
static_cast<int(Foo::*)(const std::string&)>(&Foo::bar)
```

This, however, requires you to know the exact signature, which contradicts the goal of finding the return type. Instead, you can query the return type using the [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) specifier and a helper [`declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) function:

```
std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<Foo&>().bar("")), int>::value
```